# mybatis - resultmap - nullvalues to be replaced with userdefined values

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

Mybatis resultMap Assign customized value to nullvalue 
I want to assign my customized value for nullValue returning column from my query. 
Below is my code snippet
Advanced thanks for your help

```
  <resultMap id="abcd" class="abcdVO">
    <result property="ABC" column="Col1" nullValue="No"/>
    <result property="XYZ" column="Col2" nullValue=" "/>
  </resultMap>

  <select id="abcd" parameterType ="String" resultMap="abcdMap">
     Select Col1, Col2 from xyz
  </select>
```

Comment: What database is this connecting to because you could change the query not to return null values and replace them with something else. nullValue does not exist in MyBatis and was a iBatis feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
<select id="abcd" parameterType ="String" resultMap="abcdMap">
   Select COALESCE(Col1, 'No') as Col1, COALESCE(Col2, ' ') as Col2 from xyz
</select>
```